# cannot add email on my profile

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

whenever i try to add my email address to my profile I get an error saying email address already registered! why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have duplicate accounts. I don't know what your email is, so you'll have to email us by clicking the contact link at the bottom of the page.